# An event in 2009, disconnected to the present day, yet present tense is used. Why?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

The following is an extract from *Competition and Investment Laws in India*

> **Facts**: "A" filed a complaint in 2009, before "X" alleging that "Z" was abusing its dominant position in currency derivatives trading, and **is** deliberately waiving fees in the currency derivatives segment to kill competition*

This is a 2009 case and judgment was delivered in 2011. My question is, why have they used *present tense*? Can *past perfect* be used instead of **was** and *past tense* in place of **is**?

Comment: Not enough context.

Comment: Probably better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se], but in any case,  as HotLicks says, before *anyone* can answer it, we need the fuller quote. And ideally a link to the original source, if available. For now, we'll put it on hold.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/65RJJ.jpg).  .. I  was not able to edit my post .. this is the screenshot from where I have taken the line

Comment: @Toxic You can edit your question by clicking this link [edit]. The short story is that the plaintiff is alleging the defendant engaged in one kind of malfeasance in 2009, and is still today engaging in a different kind of malfeasance. The tenses are telling you when each kind of behavior was taking place.

Comment: So .. ' today ' here means the time when he filed the complaint.  And ..we can use present tenses even though everything that was alleged is past now.

Comment: I mean ' that ' in the sentence is connected to ' alleging'... so after using ' that ' in the sentence. He used tenses from that point of view ... I don't know if I am making any sense .. :|

Comment: It's a sort of a direct quote: past tense used for the past activities and present tense for the current ones. Now, from your perspective, if you make an indirect quote of the whole story, you would say: "A" had filed a complaint in 2009, before "X" alleging that "Z"had been abusing its dominant position in currency derivatives trading, and was deliberately waiving fees in the currency derivatives segment to kill competition*

Comment: @mahmudkoya "A"  filed a complaint in 2009, before "X" alleging that "Z"had been abusing its dominant position in currency derivatives trading, and was deliberately waiving fees in the currency derivatives segment to kill competition* is this correct also ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's also been posted on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why do you favor closing this version instead of that one?  There, the duplication was pointed out one hour after posting, and the OP asked for help closing the question. // I myself don't have enough rep over there to vote to close.  // A more exact link: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/120085/18523

Comment: @aparente001: Well, you say in your answer that it's really just "sloppy writing". And I honestly doubt that any halfway-competent native speaker would think otherwise, so it's something that would only really be likely to interest learners/non-native speakers. Plus it's always *feasible* that this specific type of error is more common among speakers of Indian English (they often use the *continuous* tense in non-standard ways), so at least it could be relevant to ***other future visitors*** on ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just slightly sloppy writing.  If it had been carefully edited, "is deliberately waiving fees" would have been put in the past tense.

This happens to everyone sooner or later.  We're all only human.

Comment: yeah i guess. the book ,from where i got this ,is not usually recommended.It is like those books you read when you know you are going to fail and stuff.so yeah maybe it is just sloppy writing. 
@aparente001 thanks though

Comment: @Toxic - Please don't reject the book based on what I said in my answer.  Sometimes great analysis contains an occasional grammatical error.

Comment: yeah.it is a life saving book for students who do not read anything whole semester. >.<

Comment: @Toxic - I hope there's more wrong with that book than one inconsistent tense for you to make such a strong judgment!

Comment: That page contains multiple errors.

Comment: @MadBanners hey. could you please write those errors also it would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, no worries. *Issue: Whether NSE was abusing its dominant position in currency derivatives?* doesn't make sense. As a question, it should be "Was NSE abusing...?" As a statement, the question mark should be dropped.

Comment: @Toxic - I guess if I were trying to decide whether the book is useful to me or not, I'd be focusing more on the quality of the legal summaries and analysis than on a tense inconsistency and a mistaken question mark. // My answer expresses no judgment regarding the overally quality of the book's tenses, punctuation, or content.